# How to store data in key value pair in Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to store the data in this format in Firebase's real-time database.

```
cart
 |
 |---jywzArtx9wwdg2Vdg4JfH8qBoy1  <--[uid]
        |
        |---0 <--[index of Array]
        |   | productName: "xyz"
        |   | productPrice: 125.25
        |---1
        |   | productName: "ABC"
        |   | productPrice: 33.25
        .   .
```

This is code:

```
function handleAddCartItemSave() {
    const uid = selectorLogin.uid;
    const cartRef = ref(database, 'cart/');
    const newCartRef = push(cartRef);
    console.log("New CartRef : ", newCartRef);
    set(newCartRef, {
        selectorCart,
        uid,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("saved");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

I'm trying to store data, but only store the **uid**. `selectorCart` is not stored in Firebase realtime database. What is the mistake?

Comment: Can you share any errors that you get? Also checkout [arrays in the realtime database](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase).

Comment: If in the one `set call you show `uid` is stored, but `selectorCart` isn't , it's most likely that `selectorCart` doesn't have a value. Can you reproduce the problem when you use a hard-coded value for `selectorCart`?